# Cannot configure local DNS server on Slackware

Tags: bind, slackware, nameserver

I want to configure bind (v9) on Slackware (v14.2) so that example.com resolves to the IP address of the local Apache server.

This is my /etc/resolv.conf:

```
# Generated by dhcpcd from eth0.dhcp
# /etc/resolv.conf.head can replace this line
nameserver 192.168.0.1
# /etc/resolv.conf.tail can replace this line
```

/etc/named.conf:

```
options {
    directory "/var/named";
    /*
     * If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
     * to talk to, you might need to uncomment the query-source
     * directive below.  Previous versions of BIND always asked
     * questions using port 53, but BIND 8.1 uses an unprivileged
     * port by default.
     */
    // query-source address * port 53;
};

// 
// a caching only nameserver config
// 
zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "caching-example/named.root";
};

zone "localhost" IN {
    type master;
    file "caching-example/localhost.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "caching-example/named.local";
    allow-update { none; };
};

zone "example.com"{
    type master;
    file "/var/named/example.com.hosts";
    notify yes;
};
```

/var/named/example.com.hosts:

```
$TTL 3600
example.com. IN      SOA     sb.slackintosh.com. hostmaster.slackintosh.com. (
2002121607
3600
7200
1209600
7200 )

       IN      A  192.168.0.1
       IN      NS sb.slaskintosh.com.
       IN      MX 5 mail.example.com.

mail         IN      A       192.168.0.1
www          IN      A       192.168.0.1
```

Still, after restarting bind, example.com doesn't resolve:

```
bash-4.3# nslookup example.com
Server:         192.168.0.1

Address:        192.168.0.1#53



** server can`t find example.com: NXDOMAIN
```

What did I do wrong? Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I ran named-checkzone and this is the output:

```
bash-4.3# named-checkzone localhost /var/named/itlink.edu.hosts 
/var/named/itlink.edu.hosts:5: ignoring out-of-zone data (itlink.edu)
zone localhost/IN: has 0 SOA records
zone localhost/IN: has no NS records
zone localhost/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, substituting for directory and IP, your host file and .conf entry loaded fine for me locally... so the format doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: What does `nslookup www.example.com` give? or ` nslookup mail.example.com`?